# Python compare 2 files to get specific output

Tags: python, file, compare

So I have 2 files.

```
File A (there are no headres in this file)
ag
bb
hg_tf
gtf

File B   
field      id      ag     ytyv   bb    kgka   hg_tf    ghhg     gtf        
brown      01       0      1     0.1    2.1     7       3.5     0.8
green      02       0      0.8   1      3.12    0.87    0.5     1.8
blue       03       0      1     2.1     4.1    0.76    3.2     0.75
purple     04       0      2     4.12     2     0.89    3.1     0.8
```

I want to read over File A and get the data for only those samples from file B.

```
Output file (wanted)

field      id      ag        bb       hg_tf        gtf    ....  
brown      01       0        0.1       7            0.8
green      02       0        1         0.87         1.8
blue       03       0        2.1       0.76         0.75
purple     04       0        4.12      0.89         0.8
```

My code is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2

import collections
samples = collections.defaultdict(list)
with open('FileA.txt') as A:
  # This I hope read over fileA.
  Asamples = [l.strip() for l in A if l.strip()]            
  print(Asamples)

 with open('FileB.csv') as B:
 #And this is where I'm stuck
 ...
```

Ps: I asked a pretty similar question already but couldn't figure out how to change the code for this new situation.

Thanks everyone

Comment: Why are you klunkily reinventing both Unix text processing tools like 'cut' and 'awk', and reinventing databases with your own flat-file processing?  `gawk "{print $1,$2,$3,$5,$7,$9}" fileB.txt` (And why have you called fileB 'fileb.csv' when its contents are not comma separated values? If it *actually was* a csv, you'd have a much easier time of processing it with Python's csv module).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that files `A` and `B` looks exactly as in your code samples.

```
# read and parse A content
file_a = '/tmp/a.txt'
with open(file_a) as filea:
    a_data = [a.strip() for a in filea]

# read and parse B content
file_b = '/tmp/b.txt'
with open(file_b) as fileb:
    b_data = [[l.strip() for l in line.split()] for line in fileb]

# get target columns indexes
# include 'field' and 'id' index
indexes = [0, 1]
for a in a_data:
    try:
        indexes.append(b_data[0].index(a))
    except ValueError:
        pass

# filter data
new_data = [[line[index] for index in indexes] for line in b_data]

# separate columns by tabs and rows by line breaks
new_data_string = '\n'.join(['\t'.join(line) for line in new_data])

# save merged data
new_file = '/tmp/new.txt'
f = open(new_file, 'w')
f.write(new_data_string)
f.close()
```

Comment: Why would you use `.readlines()` to read the entire file just to iterate over those same lines?!? Just do `a_data = [a.strip() for a in filea]` after `with`

Comment: Thanks. That worked. Only stopped when some samples from file a were not in file b.

Comment: updated for cases when samples from file a are not in file b

Comment: thanks it works perfectly